# Debugging into NuGet symbol package source folder with spaces fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

Using Klondike 2.1.1, we internally host NuGet packages with their symbol packages.  Our source package in question has the following structure:

> ```
> src\
>     Project1\
>         Classes\
>             With Space\
>     Project2\
>         Classes\
>             Another Space\
> ```

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, the debugger is able to step into any class in either of the Classes folders.  If any code in either of the *Space folders is stepped into, the Find Source dialog is displayed, and no code appears in the symbol cache.

Unzipping a folder with spaces will encode them as %20.  However, NuGet does not.  Is unzipping possibly happening?

Comment: What's the version of your Klondike?

Comment: We are currently using version 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Klondike to [the latest 2.0](https://github.com/themotleyfool/Klondike/releases/tag/v2.0.0) if you are not using it.

> **New Features**
>
> - Serve source files from symbol packages in zip file instead of    unzipping them